# HttpClient DELETE with object

Tags: dotnet-httpclient

I am making a solution against a REST-interface using C# - HttpClient and Newtonsoft.Json.

One of the methods requires a DELETE with URL and a JSON-object.

I am not able to change the REST-service, so it has to be solved in my own code.

What I am missing is the DELETE-alternative to myClient.PostAsJsonAsync(Url,json-object)

I am aware, that it seems to be possible using could be solved using HttpWebRequest, but I would rather continue using HttpClient.

So does someone have a clue about how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Simply use [`HttpClient.DeleteAsync(url)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159056(v=vs.118).aspx), and why not put the target of delete into the url, like this `/api/products/id` instead of passing a json object.